# SFML & C++ - How do I make a circle rotate in a bigger range?

Tags: c++, sfml

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
// done -- orbitting circle

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000, 1000), "SFML works!");
    window.setFramerateLimit(10);

    sf::CircleShape shape(50.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
    //orbit


    sf::CircleShape shapeTwo(50.f);
    shapeTwo.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    //base

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);

        shape.setPosition(500.f, 500.f);
        shape.rotate(10.f);
        shape.setOutlineThickness(10);
        shape.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(255, 255,255));
        //orbit

        window.draw(shapeTwo);
        shapeTwo.setPosition(450.f, 450.f);
        shapeTwo.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::White);
        //base

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my code. I want the circles to be able to rotate in a bigger range instead of just around it's origin/center/whatever.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try setting the "origin/center/whatever" in order to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: You now set your shape at (500,500) and start to rotate. What happens if you put it at (100,100) instead ? The rotate radius will be about 141. and also look at tenfour's tip.. there may be a way to move the origin to e.g. (480,480), the rotate radius would be only 28, around point (480,480). Depends what you want.. but if you want to rotate around (0,0) just set the start point differently.

Answer (score 0):

The [`setOrigin`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Transformable.php#a56c67bd80aae8418d13fb96c034d25ec) function allows you changing the center point of the rotation of a shape.

```
shape.setOrigin(150.f, 150.f);
```

However, this will still only allow for circular rotations of the shape. A more flexibel method is to tie the *position* of the shape to a [time-dependent](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Clock.php) function and only use `rotate` to adjust its *orientation* in space.

For instance, the following adjustment will make your circle's position move along an elliptical curve at a speed of one full orbit per five seconds:

```
sf::Vector2f transform(float t)
{
    float const ellipse_width = 400.f;
    float const ellipse_height = 100.f;
    float const a = ellipse_width / 2.f;
    float const b = ellipse_height / 2.f;
    float const pi = 3.141592653589f;
    float const tau = 2.f * pi;
    float const period_ms = 5000.f;
    float const x = (std::fmodf(t, period_ms) / period_ms) * tau;
    return sf::Vector2f(a * std::cos(x), b * std::sin(x));
}

int main()
{
    // [...]
    sf::Clock clock;
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // [...]
        float const t = static_cast<float>(clock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds());
        shape.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(500.f, 500.f) + transform(t));
        // [...]
    }
}
```

By changing the implementation of the `transform` function, you can model motions along arbitrary curves.

Comment: what is sf::Vector2f transform(float t)

Comment: @MaxVelox `sf::Vector2f transform(float t)` is a free function at file scope that computes the positional offset of the shape as an `sf::Vector2f` object from a parameter that varies with time.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm trying to adjust the transform function so it centers the shape in the middle of the window.

Comment: How do I change the speed at which the circle rotates using sf::Vector2f without it resetting the position of the shape? Like, I have it set on an if condition, that the period_ms lowers, to make the loop faster, but doing that when the condition is fulfilled, makes the shape's position reset.